# How to get rid of the border of a Winui 3 TextBox?

Tags: c#, maui, winui-3

I have a Maui app that targets Windows, iOS and Android, within which I would like to get rid of the text entry border.
To achieve this, here is the code I wrote:

```cs
        EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Entry), (handler, view) => 
        {
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
            handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#elif ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Transparent.ToPlatform());
#elif WINDOWS
            handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
            handler.PlatformView.FocusVisualPrimaryThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
            handler.PlatformView.FocusVisualSecondaryThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
#endif
        });
```

Everything is fine on the mobile side, but on the Windows side only the first line seems to do anything `handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);` , and only if the text box doesn't have the focus.

[image]

I thought that the two other lines would solve the problem of the border that appears when the text box gets the focus, but without success.  `handler.PlatformView.FocusVisualPrimaryThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0); handler.PlatformView.FocusVisualSecondaryThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);`

So, how do I get rid of this border for good when the text box gets the focus?

(Maui .net 7 application under Windows 11)

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue about this,  and the development team have moved this issue to the Backlog milestone.

You can follow it up here: [Entry and Editor: option to disable borders and underline (focus)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7906).

Thanks for your support and feedback.